# ALOOPER_POLL_ERROR What this mean?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm doing something with Delphi Xe6 for android, and using the background service, of blong blog. When application goes back(pressing home button) and i click on his icon again, Delphi show this message:

"ALOOPER_POLL_ERROR".

I really don't have ideia what that mean or how fix that!

Can someone helpe me? I'm sorry if i can be clear with my question.

Comment: What does Google tell you if you search for `ALOOPER_POLL_ERROR`? It's really difficult to help if you don't give any information ("I'm doing something with Delphi Xe6 for android" isn't really useful) or code.

Comment: [QC Report #:  125712](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx/qcmain.aspx?d=125712)